# How to compute: $\int_{0}^1\int_{-1}^{1}(u\sqrt{4v^2+1}+v)dvdu$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

How would I compute this integral? I'm having trouble figuring out what to do with the radical
$$ \int_{0}^1\int_{-1}^{1}(u\sqrt{4v^2+1}+v)dvdu$$

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\int_{-1}^1vdv =0$ we have, $$\int_{0}^1\int_{-1}^{1}(u(4v^2+1)^{1/2}+v)dvdu =2\int_{0}^1u\int_{0}^{1}(4v^2+1)^{1/2}dvdu = \int_{0}^{1}(4v^2+1)^{1/2}dv$$

Now set $2v = \sinh t$ that is $\color{red}{dv=\frac12\cosh t dt}$ 
$$\int_{0}^{1}(4v^2+1)^{1/2}dv = \frac12\int_{0}^{\sinh^{-1}(2) }(\sinh^2+1)^{1/2}\cosh t dt \\= \frac12\int_{0}^{\sinh^{-1}(2) }\cosh^2 t dt$$

then can you take it from here?

Comment: No, the radical is giving me trouble.

Comment: Hahaha @ManaalS so .5 is the radical? please update your question

Comment: @ManaalS see that edit

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space\text{n}}\left(\text{a},\text{b}\right):=\int_0^\text{a}\int_{-\text{b}}^\text{b}\left(x+\text{y}\cdot\sqrt{1+\text{n}\cdot x^2}\right)\space\text{d}x\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
$$\int_0^\text{a}\left\{\int_{-\text{b}}^\text{b}x\space\text{d}x+\text{y}\cdot\int_{-\text{b}}^\text{b}\sqrt{1+\text{n}\cdot x^2}\space\text{d}x\right\}\space\text{d}\text{y}\tag1$$

Now, using:

- $$\int_{-\text{b}}^\text{b}x\space\text{d}x=\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{-\text{b}}^\text{b}=\frac{\text{b}^2}{2}-\frac{\left(-\text{b}\right)^2}{2}=\frac{\text{b}^2-\text{b}^2}{2}=\frac{0}{2}=0\tag2$$
- Substitute $\text{u}:=\arctan\left(x\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}\right)$, so we get:
  $$\int_{-\text{b}}^\text{b}\sqrt{1+\text{n}\cdot x^2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{n}}}\cdot\int_{\arctan\left(-\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}\right)}^{\arctan\left(\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}\right)}\sec^3\left(\text{u}\right)\space\text{d}\text{u}=$$
  $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{n}}}\cdot\int_{-\arctan\left(\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}\right)}^{\arctan\left(\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}\right)}\sec^3\left(\text{u}\right)\space\text{d}\text{u}\tag3$$
- $$\int_{-\arctan\left(\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}\right)}^{\arctan\left(\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}\right)}\sec^3\left(\text{u}\right)\space\text{d}\text{u}=$$
  $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{2\cdot\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}\cdot\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}+\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}+\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}}{\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}-\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}}\right|\right\}\tag4$$

So, we get:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space\text{n}}\left(\text{a},\text{b}\right)=\mathcal{I}_1+\mathcal{I}_1\tag5$$

Where:

- $$\mathcal{I}_1:=\int_0^\text{a}\text{y}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{n}}}\cdot\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}\cdot\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
  $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{n}}}\cdot\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}\cdot\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}\cdot\int_0^\text{a}\text{y}\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
  $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{n}}}\cdot\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}\cdot\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}\cdot\frac{\text{a}^2}{2}=$$
  $$\frac{\text{a}^2\cdot\text{b}}{2}\cdot\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}\tag6$$
- $$\mathcal{I}_2:=\int_0^\text{a}\frac{\text{y}}{2}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}+\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}}{\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}-\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}}\right|\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
  $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}+\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}}{\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}-\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}}\right|\cdot\int_0^\text{a}\text{y}\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
  $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}+\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}}{\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}-\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}}\right|\cdot\frac{\text{a}^2}{2}=$$
  $$\frac{\text{a}^2}{4}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}+\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}}{\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}-\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}}\right|\tag7$$

So:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space\text{n}}\left(\text{a},\text{b}\right)=\frac{\text{a}^2\cdot\text{b}}{2}\cdot\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}+\frac{\text{a}^2}{4}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}+\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}}{\sqrt{1+\text{b}^2\cdot\text{n}}-\text{b}\cdot\sqrt{\text{n}}}\right|\tag8$$